# Merge Sort and Selection Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, recurrence

I am having trouble developing the recurrence for an algorithm that uses recursive Merge Sort calls for list sizes greater than m. It uses Selection Sort for list sizes less or equal to m.

Here is my pseudocode:

```
proc merge_and_selection (A, p, r, m) {
if (p <= r) then
   q = (p + r)/2
   
   if r - p > m then
      merge_and_selection(A, p, q - 1, m)
      merge_and_selection(A, q + 1, r, m)
   else
      selection_sort(A, p, q - 1)
      selection_sort(A, q + 1, r)
   end

   merge(A, p, q, r)
end if 
}
```

I think the recurrence is:

[image]

with T(2) = [m(m-1)]/2

Answer (score 0):

I think more accurate formula is the following:

- T(*n*) = 2*T(*n*/2) + Theta(*n*) for *n* >= *m*/2
- T(*n*) = Theta(*n*^2) for *n* < *m*/2